# Dash callback not producing output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am working on a program that takes a user's username and password (created in the MongoDB shell) and uses that to verify them and then returns the following read query:

```
{"animal_type":"Dog", "name":"Lucy"}
```

However, when I enter the username and password, nothing gets outputted. I have tried using read() methods and dump methods, but both don't seem output anything.

I will provide both the dash framework I am working on and the main class where I have the main methods. I will gladly clarify additional information. I appreciate the help!

**Here is the dash framework I am working on:**

```
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib.parse
from bson.json_util import dumps
from CRUD import AnimalShelter

# this is a juypter dash application
app = JupyterDash('ModuleFive')
```

output
app.layout = html.Div(
[

```
    html.H1("Zane's Module 5 Assignment"),
    html.Hr(),
        
        dcc.Input(
            id="input_user".format("text"),
            type="text",
            placeholder="input type {}".format("text")),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input_passwd".format("password"),
            type="password",
            placeholder="input type {}".format("password")),
        html.Button('Execute', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
        
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id="query-out"),
    #Completed: inserted unique identifier code on line 20 and 36
    html.H3('Fin'),
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output("query-out", "children"),
    [Input("input_user".format("text"), "value"), 
     Input("input_passwd".format("password"),"value"),
     Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('input_passwd', 'value')]
)
def cb_render(userValue,passValue,n_clicks,buttonValue):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(userValue)
        password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(passValue)

        shelter = AnimalShelter(userValue, passValue)
        
        animals = shelter.read({"animal_type":"Dog", "name":"Lucy"})
        print(animals)
        
        return dumps(list(shelter.read({"animal_type":"Dog", "name":"Lucy"})))
```

**Here is my main class that has the methods:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections.
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:43282' % (username, password))
        self.AAC = self.client['AAC']

    # Create method to implement the C in CRUD
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.AAC.animals.insert_one(data)
        else:
            print("Nothing to save")
            return False

    # Create method to implement the C in CRUD
    def read(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.AAC.animals.find(data)
        else:
            print("Nothing to read")
            return False

    # Create method to implement the C in CRUD
    def update(self, data, newData):
        if data is not None:
            return self.AAC.animals.update_one(data, {'$set': newData})

        else:
            print("Nothing to update, because data parameter is empty")
            return False

       
    # Create method to implement the D in CRUD
    def delete(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.AAC.animals.delete_one(data)
            print("data deleted")
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: I'm not as familiar with MongoDB, but you're `read`ing twice. Does that `print` statement show anything? What happens if you remove it? Sometimes doing two reads like that will empty the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

First, To understand the outputs of cb_render, I would start by commenting out all of its code, then changing your return statement to this:

```
return '{}'.format(enter_your_variable_here)
```

Go through and enter each of the arguments and see what they return. This will help you better understand what it's doing, and it will ultimately be the return statement you need to use to print out your query.

Second, You should put 'username' and 'password' into your constructor, not the 'userValue' and 'passValue' arguments directly.

Third, Define your query:

```
query = {"animal_type":"Dog","name":"Lucy"}
```

Fourth, Now run your query using the client object:

```
animals = shelter.read(query)
```

Lastly, convert the python object into a json string using the dumps function

```
return '{}'.format(dumps(animals))
```

To ensure the query only returns one result, go into your animal_shelter.py script into the read() function and change 'find' to 'find_one' which is the PyMongo version of 'findOne' in the MongoDB shell.